# FizzBuzz example in Python for game manual

Tags: python, fizzbuzz

I'm developing an implementation of the FizzBuzz game as part of an edutainment game for a retro video game platform. In its manual, I want to mention the history of writing a bot for the FizzBuzz game as a programmer screening test since [Jeff Atwood's blog post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/), including sample answers in a few popular programming languages. But I don't want to confuse readers with poorly written code.

So is there anything unclear or unpythonic about my approach to FizzBuzz?

```
# Each of several divisors has a name. For each number,
# print the names of all divisors that divide the number,
# if any.  Otherwise print the number itself.
divs = [
    (3, "fizz"),
    (5, "buzz"),
]
for n in range(1, 101):
    # Make a string containing names of divisors of n
    ndivs = ''.join(name for (divisor, name) in divs
                    if n % divisor == 0)
    # If the string is empty, print the number instead
    print(ndivs or n)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the naming used here is a little confusing for new coders.

The name `div` would be read as a divisor, and elements called `divisor` are then extracted from it.

Perhaps use something with more clear indication of what it is, like `divsor_pairs` or `divsor_names`

```
divsor_pairs = [
    (3, "fizz"),
    (5, "buzz"),
]
for index in range(1, 101):
    divsor_output = ''.join(name for (divisor, name) in divsor_pairs
                    if index % divisor == 0)
    print(divsor_output or index)
```

Answer (score 10):

Nicely done! The great thing about this implementation that it's easy to extend (for example if you want to add `(7, "jazz")`. I have only some minor nitpicks.

Tuples are immutable, as opposed to lists.
Since the list of fizz-buzz-jazz definitions don't change during the run of the program,
the `divs` list can be a tuple.
Tuples are faster than lists.

```
divs = (
    (3, "fizz"),
    (5, "buzz"),
)
```

The parentheses are unnecessary around `(divisor, name)`:

> ```
> ndivs = ''.join(name for (divisor, name) in divs
>                 if n % divisor == 0)
> ```

This may be a matter of taste,
but I'd find this line more readable on a single line:

```
ndivs = ''.join(name for divisor, name in divs if n % divisor == 0)
```

Comment: I slightly object to using a tuple for divs because a) speed is irrelevant here and b) tuples are often used for inhomogenous data (position in tuple matters) while lists are often used for homogenous data.

Comment: @Jasper speed is not the main concern, that's why I added that as the last point, more of an additional good thing. The more important is that it's immutable, which is perfect for the purpose. Preferring a better technique, even if it's not required, is a good practice to build good habits

Comment: @Jasper Can you please elaborate a bit on b) point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1708702/3456281 and the second comment. E.g. if you have a coordinate pair, a tuple should be used because the first and second element have a different meaning, and adding elements to this pair also makes no sense, because your coordinate lives in 2D or 3D (or any other fixed-D).

Comment: @confused00 In other words, the conceptual difference is analogous to that between an array and a `struct` in C, except that a `tuple` is immutable. The semantics of Python `list` invite appending more divisor-name pairs, such as `(7, "feed")` to produce clickbait at 35. The only speed difference is at construction time anyway.

Comment: @Jasper, I see, thanks. Yet I'm still not sure why you'd oppose using tuples in this case. The order seems to matter later on in `(name for (divisor, name) in divs if n % divisor)`, and even if it didn't, given that the structure is not supposed to be mutated in the code, why wouldn't it be better to signify this via making it a tuple?

Comment: I think in this case one can argue for both `list` and `tuple`. Regardless of mutability, the inner thing `(3, 'fizz')` should be a tuple, because `thing[0]` has a different meaning than `thing[1]` and there never will be a `thing[2]`. For the outer thing, **I** would prefer a list, because all elements of it have the same meaning, and adding more elements is meaningful.